# CSS files loading but CSS not being applied

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, datatables, bootstrap-4

I have an ASP.NET MVC project using `Boostrap 4` and `jQuery DataTables`.  For both tools, the `CSS` files load but none of the CSS rules are applied.  Looking at the network tab of Chrome dev tools, content type is coming over as text/css.  Here's the code within the `head` tag of the main layout page:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
@*<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/bootstrap.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />*@
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")"rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/pushy.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/MyStyle.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/font-awesome.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/theme.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/DataTables/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
@*<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/DataTables/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css")" />*@
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/DataTables/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

I've tried using `runat="server"` in both the `link` and `head` tags, using `@Styles.Render` instead of a `link` tag, swapping out the `minified` file with the full one, `href` with and without `@Url.Content()`, and using a file directly from `Bootstrap`, all with no success (haven't been able to find any other solutions on SO either).

`MyStyle.css` loads and applies properly, but not the `Bootstrap` or `DataTables` `CSS`.  This is driving me nuts trying to figure out the issue - what am I missing?

I'm running `.NET 4.6.1` on `Visual Studio 2017`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually another css file from _Layout.cshtml overwrites the view page css file.removed main.css from Viewpage.cshtml

Comment: Unless one of the files I'm including overwrites another file I include, don't think that's it.  Our team uses a template to keep a consistent appearance across our apps.  The `Layout` in `_ViewStart.cshtml` file points to a file called `_LayoutSections.cshtml`, which has the `Layout` set to the `_CustomLayout.cshtml` file.  I only have `CSS` files referenced in the `_CustomLayout.cshtml` file (though I have tried to have them in the `_LayoutSections.cshtml` file instead).